# How to see my deleted questions?

Tags: support

I just discovered that my question about democracy and popularity was deleted. How can I see the source?

Comment: At the risk of coming across self-promotional, I know the other question looks worse, but it does have an answer (by me) that does show all of one's own deleted questions and answers.

Comment: @JJJ How can a question from 2013 be a duplicate of a question from 2017?

Comment: Because it has a more useful answer. It's actually pretty common becuase newer questions get asked and may get more attention in the heat of the moment. I agree that the dupe target is poor due to the user wanting to make a point but there's no easy way around that, I think. I would agree with editing the question to make it less if a rant though. Also, note that the dupe is not something to be worried about personally, it just increases findability (of the answers).

Comment: @JJJ Your points may be valid. But: *"This question has been asked before and already has"*: NOO, this ret-conningly stupid in its phrasing for this use case. Wherever (here or MetaSE) this banner text can be changed, it *needs* changing for precisely Anixx's observed perplexity (and a few more actually). In this variant it retains a flair of "why didn't you search before posting"

Comment: @LangLangC I'm sorry, I'm not in charge of the phrasing. Actually, your comment, too, is sort of [a duplicate of this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha#comment955549_147651). :-) I agree with you that the phrasing could be better but I think that's better addressed on the main meta site.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a [fairly recent new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-recently-deleted-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492) that allows you to link to your own deleted questions and answers

1. Go to your [profile](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/1470/anixx)
2. click on the [Questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/1470/anixx?tab=questions) header.
3. scroll to the bottom and click on `deleted recent questions`

Comment: Thanks, but this link does not give the question I was looking for. Could it be completely erased?

Comment: @Anixx do you remember the title of your question?  so long as you can link to it, you can see the question.  some browsers allow you to type keywords(such as the title of the question) into the url bar, and they'll remember pages that you've been to.  try typing your question's title into the url bar and see if it comes up

Comment: Thanks, I found it: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/why-the-us-tries-to-convince-us-that-to-be-democratic-and-legitimate-the-governm